# Querying Relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got these tables:

```
table: investigation
id
name
start_city
end_city

table: city
id
name
```

`start_city` and `end_city` in table `investigation` refers to `city.id`.

This is my `Investigation` model:

```
public function start_city(){
    return $this->hasOne('City', 'id', 'start_city');
}

public function end_city(){
    return $this->hasOne('City', 'id', 'end_city');
}
```

`City` model:

```
public function start_city(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Investigation', 'id', 'start_city');
}

public function end_city(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Investigation', 'id', 'end_city');
}
```

`Investigation` controller:

```
public function show($id){
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump(Investigation::find($id)->start_city->name);
}
```

I always get `Trying to get property of non-object`. I suspect that the relationship is somehow 'broken'. How do I fix this? I tried to switch `hasOne` and `belongsTo` but it doesn't change anything.

PS: Please don't comment on code convention since I 'translated' this code from other language where it doesn't have plural form.

Comment: You must use `camelCase` for relations names in order to use `dynamic properties` feature of the Eloquent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename all your relations to `camelCase`:

```
public function startCity(){
    return $this->hasOne('City', 'id', 'start_city');
}

public function endCity(){
    return $this->hasOne('City', 'id', 'end_city');
}
```

and the same for all other models.

Then you can use `dynamic properties` like below:

```
$investigation->startCity;
```

---

Otherwise you can't use dynamic properties and you would need this:

```
$investigation->start_city()->getResults()->name;
```